# Installed new SSD on Macbook Air now won't let me reinstall OS

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, install, ssd

I have a 2012 Macbook Air. It shipped with 64GB SSD but I upgraded it to 240GB using a 3rd party manufacturer. I was planning on doing a clean install on the system but when I checked to make sure if I could download it, the installer failed to verify that I could install it on the machine. It is like the installer isn't recognising it as a Mac. Any advice?

Comment: What was the exact error?

Comment: You should be able to install from a USB drive if nothing else. http://osxdaily.com/2012/02/17/make-bootable-os-x-10-8-mountain-lion-usb-install-drive/

Answer (score 1):

OK so ultimately I was able to solve the problem and here is how.

I noticed that when tried to install OSX straight away it failed but when I selected a drive that had OSX installed on it, it validated successfully. However once I had erased the drive it no longer contained a copy hence validation failed. I still had my old SSD which contained a full copy so when I plugged that in via USB and selected it in startup disk, the installer validated it and allowed me to install OSX on the new drive.

Answer (score 0):

Is your Macbook Air as a registered purchase on the Mac Server, I use to have this problem, then I registered by entering a valid date of buying, which it asked me for (a copy of the bill is required to do so). Now I can Install the Updates, Check by putting your Serial number here [Apple warranty check](https://selfsolve.apple.com/agreementWarrantyDynamic.do)
[image]